# Azure AD Service to Service calls using Client Credentials - Shared Secret

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have an API hosted on the cloud and a daemon app client in the same organization and on the same network but on my local machine. I have double and triple checked the setup but still not able to connect them with each other.

So to look at the problem I divided them into two sub-problems.

1. Connecting Daemon App to Azure AD retrieving the token and then accessing Microsoft Graph using the token. 
   Error post retrieval of token.

```
Failed to call the Web Api: Forbidden
Content: {
  "error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "2646f5f8-9c25-482d-a89f-f14ca6c06cf7",
      "date": "2019-07-22T01:13:30"
    }
  }
```

I used this [Azure Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-acquire-token) and [Sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2) to produce the error above.

[image: Client API Permissions]

2. Accessing the API using the daemon app - So I never reached to because I never was able to pass step 1.

Any thoughts on how can I get to fix this. Am I am missing something simple?

Comment: I know it's exhausting but I think you should share your code which tries to access the API. Did you enabled "Implicit flow" which is only possible via direct editing of the manifest in the portal on the API app-reg? Just one question out of the wide area of possible errors here.

Comment: @AlexanderSchmidt I am using MS's Sample DotNet Core App. Link above in the description. It's throwing the error. The only thing which I would like mention is the code uses https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users and I have Azure AD Graph but not sure that would make a difference.

Comment: Looks like you have granted some delegated permissions to the app. Only application permissions apply with client credentials flow.

Comment: @juunas actually problem is resolved using the below solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations) is different from [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). So there are two ways to make it work.

**1**.**Use Microsoft Graph API**.

You should grant the application microsoft graph api permission.

[image]

**2**.**Use Azure AD Graph API**.

You need to update the code as below.

a.Change the scope to `https://graph.windows.net/.default`.

b.Change the api to `GET https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users?api-version=1.6`

**Note:**

> We strongly recommend that you use Microsoft Graph instead of Azure AD
>   Graph API to access Azure Active Directory resources.